# Undefined class JWTAuth

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, token, jwt, json-web-token

While using JWT with laravel, I am getting a message in my editior -

```
Undefined class JWTAuth
```

even after adding the following lines :-

```
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
```

I followed this tutorial https://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-and-angularjs-token-based-auth-part1/ and made the changes but still

app/config.php has :-

```
Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWTAuthServiceProvider::class,
```

and

```
'JWTAuth'   => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::class,
'JWTFactory' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTFactory::class
```

My TokenAuthController -

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    try {
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
    }

    // if no errors are encountered we can return a JWT
    return response()->json(compact('token'));
}

public function getAuthenticatedUser()
{
    try {

        if (! $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());

    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e) {

        return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());

    }

    return response()->json(compact('user'));
}
```

Because of this, tokens are not being generated.

Pls Help.

Comment: Is the error in your editor only, or it really throws error in runtime?

Comment: @MinaYoussef - only in the editor, and because of it I think token is not generated.

Comment: If no errors are thrown then Laravel can resolve the dependencies. Would you share the code that generates the token?

Comment: @MinaYoussef - i edited the post, added TokenAuthController.php code. This is the tutorial I am following - https://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-and-angularjs-token-based-auth-part1/

Comment: What is the output of the authenticate action?

Comment: when i give $credentials manually, and test it on Postman, I get a token. But when authenticate() is called from getAuthenticatedUser(),, i get a error saying, token could not be parsed

Comment: So, the tokens are actually generated. That's the first step. How do you pass the token back to getAuthenticatedUser()?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95828/discussion-between-stacy-j-and-mina-youssef).

Answer (score 1):

So reference to the discussion on the main question, the whole application is working fine. You just need to pass the parameters correctly between Angular and Laravel.